# show file upload progress in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to implement file upload progress bar in one of my project.But,having searched a lot , i am not able to find how to find bytes of file uploaded.
Can someone tell me how  to find bytes of file uploaded in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti_1.html

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, please add the site's content to your answer instead of posting just the URL. [Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150214234227/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti_1.html)

Comment: It's quite an in-depth article on a 7 year old question.  I'll pass thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to use some third party upload control. [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is a nice one you may take a look at.

Comment: +1 for Plupload, i especially love its ability to auto detect browser capabilities and use the method with most bling bling! like html5, flash, gears etc.

Comment: Awesome integration of plupload! just include js and configure like you want. no server side messing and all that! Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

The jquery plugin [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) is really good, it has built in progress bars for multiple files and has ability to get progress feedback for custom progress bars.

**Note:** Is only possible to get this type of feedback using Flash (and/or Silverlight I believe) without going a heavier route like ActiveX/Java.

**Update:**

This is also possible using plain html and javascript, see this jquery plugin for an example:
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
For asp.net mvc also have a look at this: [Can i upload file in jquery dialog in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167638/can-i-upload-file-in-jquery-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: not true, its completely possible to achieve a progress bar with bytes and stuff using pure ajax.

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: ok great! didnt know that, please can you provide a a link to an example.

Answer (score 2):

jQueryFileUpload works well for me, I have some ASP.Net bindings at https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net

Comment: This fellow is the authour of jQueryFileUpload via asp.net!

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue in our mvc project a month or two ago. after fiddling around on the internet and trying a few different implementations, i ended up on the one suggest by steve sanderson using swfupload. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

it will work just fine in 90% of browsers and for the few that don't support flash it falls back nicely. just copy the code and dump it into your project, it worked just fine in our MVC2 project.

Comment: use plupload and you'll get all the fallback-ing for free... and in the newest browsers you even get html5 or gears support.

Comment: sounds cool will def have a look if i ever need to do something similar again.. also, sandersons implementation is free?

Answer (score 1):

Is it the standard upload control with ASP?